# SQL: Calculate working hours between two time intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, gaps-and-islands, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to calculate the monthly working hours of each delivery guy. This is data of a delivery company, and each delivery guy has a different time where he starts his shift and ends his shift.

This is a sample of how the table looks like:

| Type_ID | Delivery_Guy_ID | Date_Created |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5000 | 210 | 2020-11-16 16:34:43 |
| 7000 | 210 | 2020-11-16 16:35:24 |
| 3000 | 210 | 2020-11-16 16:35:46 |
| 3000 | 210 | 2020-11-16 16:37:41 |
| 4000 | 210 | 2020-11-16 16:39:41 |
| 3000 | 210 | 2020-11-16 16:42:53 |
| 4000 | 210 | 2020-11-16 16:47:53 |
| 3000 | 210 | 2020-11-16 16:48:16 |
| 4000 | 210 | 2020-11-16 16:50:16 |
| 3000 | 210 | 2020-11-16 16:53:01 |
| 2000 | 210 | 2020-11-16 18:53:07 |

Type ID = 2000 refers to 'Shift Ended' and type ID = 7000 refers to 'Shift Started'. A delivery guy might start his shift and end his shift several times during the day.

This is the query I tried:

```
WITH working_hours_cte AS 
( 
       SELECT * 
       FROM   ( 
                       SELECT   id AS id 
                                , 
                                type_id AS type_id 
                                , 
                                delivery_guy_id AS delivery_guy_id
                                , 
                                Timezone('Africa/Cairo', date_created) as date_created
                       FROM     delivery_guys_event
                       ORDER BY delivery_guy_id,
                                date(date_created), 
                                date_created ) AS t 
       WHERE  t.date_created >= date('11-01-2020') 
       AND    t.date_created <= date('11-30-2020') ), get_shift_start_time_cte AS 
( 
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                ON( 
                                                t.delivery_guy_id) t.* , 
                                t.date_created::timestamptz AS shift_start_time 
                FROM            working_hours_cte  AS t 
                WHERE           t.type_id = 7000 
                GROUP BY        1, 
                                2, 
                                3, 
                                4 
                                
                ORDER BY        t.delivery_guy_id, 
                                date(date_created), 
                                t.date_created), get_shift_end_time_cte AS 
( 
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                ON( 
                                                t.delivery_guy_id) t.* , 
                                t.date_created::timestamptz AS shift_end_time 
                FROM            working_hours_cte  AS t 
                WHERE           t.type_id = 2000 
                GROUP BY        1, 
                                2, 
                                3, 
                                4
                ORDER BY        t.delivery_guy_id, 
                                date(date_created), 
                                t.date_created), get_working_hours_cte1 AS 
( 
          SELECT    base.* , 
                    (date_part('day', ap.shift_end_time::timestamptz - aa.shift_start_time::timestamptz) * 24 + date_part('hour', ap.shift_end_time::timestamptz - aa.shift_start_time::timestamptz)) * 60 + date_part('minute', ap.shift_end_time::timestamptz - aa.shift_start_time::timestamptz) AS working_hours
                     
          FROM      working_hours_cte AS base 
          LEFT JOIN get_shift_start_time_cte   AS aa 
          ON        base.delivery_guy_id = aa.delivery_guy_id
          LEFT JOIN get_shift_end_time_cte AS ap 
          ON        base.delivery_guy_id = ap.delivery_guy_id) 
SELECT    u.NAME                                          AS delivery_guy_name
          , 
          round(sum(timings.working_hours::numeric),0)/60 AS working_hours 
FROM      get_working_hours_cte1                          AS timings 
LEFT JOIN delivery_guys_contacts                          AS u  
ON        timings.delivery_guy_id = u.id 
WHERE     timings.date_created >= date('11/01/2020') 
AND       timings.date_created <= date('11/30/2020') 
GROUP BY  delivery_guy_name 
ORDER BY  delivery_guy_name ASC
```

Desired Output:

| Delivery_guy_name | Working_hours |
| --- | --- |
| John | 200 |
| Michael | 150 |
| Joe | 230 |

I tried to self-join as well but none seems to be giving the correct number of hours. Can someone please tell me where the problem is?

Comment: please provide desired output as well

Comment: I just edited the question

Answer (score 1):

How about summing the time difference between the current row and the next row, *excepted if* the current row is an end of shift? That could be easily done with window functions:

```
select delivery_guy_id, sum(diff) as total_diff
from (
    select delivery_guy_id, 
        lead(date_created) over(partition by delivery_guy_id order by date_created) 
            - date_created as diff
    from mytable
) t
wxhere type_id <> 2000
group by delivery_guy_id
```

This would work if there are no record outside the start/end of ships - that is, an end of shift is always followed by a start of shift.

Comment: Thank you so much for the heads-up! I organized the data and only included ends shifts and first shifts, with end shifts always followed by start shifts. I couldn't partition by delivery_guy_id because I wanted to look at each shift independently. In other words, subtract row 2 from row 1 and row 4 from row 3. It worked when I used the ntile() function and assigned the same row number to every two rows. I then partitioned by the row numbers & sum over() partition by delivery_guy_id. So thanks for putting me on the right track!